# Java v Python floating point arithmetic

Tags: python, java

I am trying to convert some Java code to Python, but seem to be running into issues with floating point precision.

I am unable to change the Java code, so the solution needs to be in the Python.

Java code:

```java
float Ax = -0.13044776f;
float Ay = -0.17653446f;
float Az = 9.8041935f;

final float Ex = -40.55481f;
final float Ey = -22.624207f;
final float Ez = -57.284546f;

float Hx = Ey * Az - Ez * Ay;
```

In Java `Hx` has a value of `-231.9248`

Python code:

```py
Ax = -0.13044776
Ay = -0.17653446
Az = 9.8041935

Ex = -40.55481
Ey = -22.624207
Ez = -57.284546

Hx = float(Ey * Az - Ez * Ay)
```

In Python `Hx` has a value of `-231.92479960650965`

Why is there more points of precision in Python, and how can I replicate the Java behaviour?

Comment: Have you tried using `double` instead of `float`? AFAIK Python uses 64-bit precision floating point numbers

Comment: Have you tried rounding the value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've answered my own question with the knowledge that others have shared here.

`numpy` has a `float32` data type https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.scalars.html#numpy.float32

Python code

```py
Ax = float32(-0.13044776)
Ay = float32(-0.17653446)
Az = float32(9.8041935)
    
Ex = float32(-40.55481)
Ey = float32(-22.624207)
Ez = float32(-57.284546)

Hx = Ey * Az - Ez * Ay
```

`Hx` is now `-231.9248`

Answer (score 1):

Change `float` to `double` in you Java code. Now `Hx` will contain `-231.9247949756118` when you keep the `f` suffix in your numbers or `-231.92479960650965` if you remove it. You need to understand that floating point numbers have an intrinsic imprecision. In Java, if you need exact precision, you will need to use the `BigDecimal` class:

```
BigDecimal Ax = new BigDecimal( "-0.13044776" );
BigDecimal Ay = new BigDecimal( "-0.17653446" );
BigDecimal Az = new BigDecimal( "9.8041935" );

BigDecimal normsqA = Ax.multiply( Ax ).add( Ay.multiply( Ay ).add( Az.multiply( Az ) ) );
BigDecimal g = new BigDecimal( "9.81" );   
BigDecimal freeFallGravitySquared = new BigDecimal( "0.01" ).multiply( g ).multiply( g );   

BigDecimal Ex = new BigDecimal( "-40.55481" );
BigDecimal Ey = new BigDecimal( "-22.624207" );
BigDecimal Ez = new BigDecimal( "-57.284546" );

BigDecimal Hx = Ey.multiply( Az ).subtract( Ez.multiply( Ay ) );

System.out.println( Hx );
```

Now, `Hx` contains `-231.92479960650966`.

### EDIT: I think I misunderstood your question.

I think you can round the value in Python to "simulate" the less precision that you need. Something like:

```
Hx = round( float(Ey * Az - Ez * Ay), 4 )
```

Comment: I am unable to change the Java code, so I need to get the less precise number in Python, rather than increasing the precision in Java.

Comment: @Sam As far as I'm aware, Python doesn't have 32-bit float (single/binary32) support, only 64-bit (double/binary64).

Comment: @Sam I think you just need to round your number to achieve what you need.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Python doesn't (at least typically), but NumPy does.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said: Instead of `float` use `double` as it has more precision to match the precision that Python is using. Also note that you will need to change your literals to not be declared as `floats` (like `-0.13044776`**`f`** is)

```java
double Ax = -0.13044776;
double Ay = -0.17653446;
double Az = 9.8041935;

final double normsqA = (Ax * Ax + Ay * Ay + Az * Az);
final double g = 9.81;
final double freeFallGravitySquared = 0.01 * g * g;

final double Ex = -40.55481;
final double Ey = -22.624207;
final double Ez = -57.284546;
double Hx = Ey * Az - Ez * Ay;

System.out.println(Hx);
// result: -231.92479960650965 matching Python exactly
```